# Getting error while running test ng - FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setBaseURL

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am trying to run and getting **FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setBaseURL**
Please help. What's going wrong Here's the code......

```
 public class GuestCheckoutTest {

            public WebDriver driver ;
            public String baseURL = "http://www.google.com";

        @BeforeClass
        public void setBaseURL(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseURL);
        }

        @Test(priority= 0)
        void EmailPasswordEntry() {
            // Entering Email and Password values

            driver.findElement(By.id("loginRegister")).click();
            WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("head_username"));
            email.clear();
            email.sendKeys("dhruv.bhatnagar@timesinternet.in");


        }
    }
```

Error is as below:

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setBaseURL
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

=> Your project seems to not having the appropriate jar as dependency.

Solution: add the jar in the classpath (depend on your IDE and/or build tool)

Comment: Thanks ..got this fixed!

Comment: Cool. Then you can accept and up vote the response ;)